# KN-Q7A - A good place to start?

Tags: diy, transceiver

I have decent circuit knowledge and would like to get into some homebrew operating, specifically voice. Would the KN-Q7A be a good place to start? If so can I just get the parts and do the circuit myself? Or should I buy the kit?

Comment: Hi mjr. As this question stands, it might well be at risk of being closed as "primarily opinion-based" because of your asking "would this be a good place to start?", which is inherently about peoples' opinions rather than facts. Generally speaking, on Stack Exchange we prefer questions that seek fact, not opinion. You may want to [edit] the question such that it asks less for opinion and more for facts. For example, you may want to consider reframing the question in terms of "what to look for in a kit?", but please take care to focus the question so it doesn't end up too broad instead.

Answer (score 1):

I just read the description of those kits, and I like the concept a lot.

About the only criticism I have, is that the kits only covers 20 kHz (30 kHz on 20m) because of the crystal pulling trick they use. I would find it extremely frustrating not to be able to tune the entire band. But that is just me!

On the other hand, the mixer (NE602) is used as oscillator, and removing the crystal and inserting a signal from a DDS signal generator will solve that perfectly (there are several kits on the market for DDS oscillators). So, you can start with the original kit, and later replace the VXO by an external, digital VFO. That way, you can tune the entire band!

The circuit looks very well thought out!

On the question whether to gather the parts yourself, I have the impression you'd have a hard time to beat the price (and the convenience).

Answer (score 0):

On the last two questions, I once harbored ambitions of building all my own stuff from scratch. Kits are much easier.